# Proper Way to Work with Git on Satchmo/Django Project

Tags: database, django, sqlite, e-commerce, satchmo

I've built a django/satchmo ecommerce site which is starting to get some traffic, and I am having a problem because I do not have a smart way to deal with database changes. When I develop the site on my local system, I make changes to the layout and the DB, which manages the product attributes.

When I want to push new developments to the server, I have to overwrite the server database which has information about recent shoppers and purchases.

What I want to do is "merge" the two databases together so that new purchases still stay recorded in the database, but which also allow me to push local changes to the server.

I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you using [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)? (if not, you should)

in particular, have a look at [data migrations](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html#datamigration)